# Genrate Apk from React Native app , JDK Error

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, gradle

here is the error while building the signed apk
the following screenshot is the packages and version used within the app.

```
> Task :react-native-firebase_messaging:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_291). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running `jetify`? [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64305705/13772644)

Comment: yes , no difference @Moistbobo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for solving this issue , you should update your jdk and also keep your firebase libraries updated .

then run `./gradlew clean` within Project's root and remove the `build` folder within app.

it should solve the issue!

Comment: I have the same exact error but I'm not using bare react native. Any ideas?